# S3 Restriced URLs vs. Cloudfront Signed URLs

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We are considering moving our file delivery to Cloudfront.

Currently, we generate "secure" URLs for our file delivery on a individual basis which look like: 
http://downloads.xxxxx.com/1/2005-01-01_2006-01-01.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=012NFZM3D44FSG20CP82&Expires=1495287427&response-cache-control=No-cache&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D2005-01-01_2006-01-01.csv&Signature=tWAeES3rhAlv2SQoZkqyYJEexH0%3D

Is there an easy way to apply Cloudfront to the URL above, or do we need to configure them from scratch using Signed URLs? Would the S3 authenticated URL "pass-through" using Cloudfront if I create a simple distribution there?

Answer (score 2):

It is theoretically possible to configure CloudFront to pass-through an S3 signed URL, but doing so would defeat all caching, so... no, it's not a viable solution.

CloudFront uses an [entirely different algorithm for signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html), so there's not a way to simply transform an existing S3 signed URL into a CloudFront signed URL.

Note also that you'll need to embed the existing `response-*` parameters in the URL before signing it.  CloudFront should still pass them through so that S3 can modify its response as indicated.

---

Unrelated: one feature you might find interesting is that with CloudFront signed URLs, you actually have the optional ability to embed the client's IP address in the URL in such a way that the URL can only be used from a single IP address.  This isn't something that can be done in a straightforward way with an S3 signed URL.